# JavaScript: Map issue

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with my code.

```
function openOrSenior(data) {
    "use strict";

    let myMap = new Map(data);
    let test = [];
    let old = [];
    let val = [];


    for(let key of myMap.keys()){
            old.push(key);
    }

    for(let value of myMap.values()){
            val.push(value);
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(old[i] >= 55 && val[i] > 7){
            test.push("Senior");
        } else { test.push("Open");}
    }
    return test;
}
```

If I have an input like this and debug my code:

> openOrSenior([[21, 21], [0, 0], [90, 8], [1, 1], [60, 12], [90, 7], [75, 11], [55, 10], [90, 9], [54, 9]]);

My map have this key&value pairs :[myMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryWkh.png)

It's not in the right sequence and does not contain all key-->values pairs, but if I take a subset of my input like this:

> openOrSenior([[21, 21], [0, 0], [90, 8]]);

The Code does what I want:[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXXYc.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Best Regards

Comment: A Map has unique keys, so the second attempt to add 90 as a key will override the value stored at the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented above, a Map has unique keys. You can however extend the Map class and create a Multimap. A very (very very) simple implemantation is found below. Below will add all the values to an array found at key, pushing to the existing value if the key is already in our Multimap, you can add elements by using set()

```js
class Multimap extends Map {
  constructor(arrOfArr = [[]]) {
    super(arrOfArr);
  }

  set(key, value) {
    super.set(key, super.has(key) ? super.get(key).concat(value) : [value]);
  }
}

let foo = new Multimap([[21, 21], [0, 0], [90, 8], [1, 1], [60, 12], [90, 7], [75, 11], [55, 10], [90, 9], [54, 9]]);
foo.set(21, 22);

for (let [k,v] of foo.entries()) {
  console.log(k, v);
}
```